# PHP Iframes and Sessions

Tags: php, session, iframe

I have iframe which will be accessed from different domains.

Eg.

```
Iframe - www.iframe.com
Domain1 - www.domain1.com 
Domain2 - www.domain2.com`
```

Both domain will access iframe with 
 different userid

Problem is when i access the domain1 the same session is being used in domain2. But i don't want to use the same because both domains will be having different userid.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you pass userid as a parameter in the iframe src on Domain1 and Domain2? If yes, then maybe you could use different session vars depending on that...

Comment: Yes i can pass the userid as parameter. Can you please explain how i can do that?

Comment: Assuming that you use cookies, it is impossible to share a session between `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`. This problem shouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you aim, but i'll edit the answer if you give more details.
Let's say...

**DOMAIN 1** `index.php`

```
<?php
// here you have a specific userid
$userid = "user1";
// when you load the iframe, you send userid as parameter
?>
<iframe src="www.iframe.com?userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>"></iframe>
```

**DOMAIN 2** `index.php`

```
<?php
// the same thing, but different userid
$userid = "user2";
?>
<iframe src="www.iframe.com?userid=<?php echo $userid; ?>"></iframe>
```

**IFRAME** `index.php`

```
<?php
// start session
session_start();
//let's say you already have a defined user structure in the SESSION
if (!isset($_SESSION["users"])) {
  $_SESSION["users"] = array(
    "user1" => array("name" => "USER 1"),
    "user2" => array("name" => "USER 2")
  );
}
// now, you can check the userid from the GET parameters to select the correct session
$userid = false;
if (isset($_GET["userid"]))
  $userid = $_GET["userid"];
// check if user is valid
if ($userid && isset($_SESSION["users"][$userid])) {
  // userid is valid
  echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION["users"][$userid]["name"];
} else {
  // userid is not valid
  echo "Who are you, stranger?";
}
```

Note: you have to make sure the users are logged in somehow (validate the user with a password, because anyone can change the GET parameters...)